# Google Analytics query explorer doesn't return custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

My instance of Google Analytics is setup to track UserId, and I can see the unique ID that I am pushing to a custom dimension called User Id (ga:customdimension3).

[image]

Query explorer shows this custom dimension, but returns a blank result set:

[image]

What's even more bizarre, is that I can use the custom dimension as a filter (so long as it's not also a dimension):

[image]

And it filters to just that one user.

Comment: I have tried and did not find your problem, I see the results of userid and sessions. It is very strange however that you have so many sessions for each user, is this data you expect?

Comment: @MichelePisani, yes, that screenshot was looking at a very wide range, so the high number of sessions per user is expected.